# Low-dropout buck converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, buck

Do they even exist?

I looking for a solution where I have a system with the voltage can vary between 12-20 V, and I need a stable 12 V 5 A output (or more).

I'm using a regular cheap buck converter, the problem with these is that there is a 2 V difference between the input and output so when the input is 12 V the output is 10 V and I would need 12 V.

What solutions would you recommend?

Comment: Is a buck-boost converter an option?

Comment: Some buck converters are capable of operation with VIN = VOUT (they stop switching and just connect VOUT to VIN), but you still have a voltage drop at VOUT due to the Rdson of the internal FET. If you really need exactly 12 V out with 12 V at 5 A then you'd need a buck-boost converter.

Comment: If you want to use a buck converter, you need to find a controller IC that can do 100% duty cycle. If isn't 100%, you wont be able to get Vin = Vout.

Comment: @Null RDS will have an effect, though it should be very small. Maybe 0.1-.5V or so. With a 2V drop that tells me there's a max duty cycle of below 100%. This application would need to use a specific controller IC that uses an external mosfet so that a low RDS on mosfet can be chosen and is capable of 100% duty cycle.

Comment: @bunker89320 Yes, Rdson should not account for a 2 V drop but the OP has not specified the minimum acceptable output voltage nor the max output current ("5 A output or more") so it's not clear how low the output can/would drop even for a known Rdson..

Comment: buck boost looks interesting. Can you recommend a specific brand? Well something with a tolerance of -0.5V or less. So if it gets 12V in it outputs 11.5V in worst case but I would prefer if it gets 12V input it outputs 12V and there is no loss.

Comment: MP8715 is this good? although it says 4A max

Comment: bump... any good brands to do this?

Comment: We can't recommend any particular brands, must give you suggestions for what type of product to use (e.g. buck-boost converter, or perhaps a buck converter that can use 100% duty cycle if the Rdson drop is acceptable to your application).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say don't ignore N MOSFET based DC-DCs just because most can't run at 100% duty cycle. Anything that runs on 12V +/-5% should run fine on 11.8V too.

So why not use a chip like [LTC3851](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3851fb.pdf) that can run at 99% duty cycle?

There are other such chips, and of course the PMOS based ones which can run at 100% duty cycle.

Note that using a NMOS does not mean it can't run at near 100% duty cycle.

What matters is first and foremost minimum off-time (that's specified in datasheet), because if that is too long, then that reduces the maximum duty cycle.

Then, the ability of the various logistic circuits in the chip to with with Vout close to Vin, for example if there is a current sense amp on the inductor, then its common mode sets limits on output voltage, so it has to be able to sense close to Vin. Other current sense architectures don't have such limits but have other tradeoffs.

Then, as a bonus, there is the ability of the converter to skip cycles if needed, basically just output an off-pulse when the bootstrap cap needs recharging, and otherwise keep the top MOSFET fully ON. LTC3851 has this feature.

If you want exactly 12V out with 12V in, then you have to consider the usual 5% accuracy on 12V in, so it has to work down to 11.4V and still output 12V while compensating for losses in the RdsON and inductor, which means you will need a buck-boost. That's more expensive, complex, and less efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but according to the datasheet: INTV CC Peak Output Current ..................................50mA, I need 5A.

Comment: @Thermaltake which has absolutely nothing to do with the output current of the switching regulator. You have to use an external MOSFET and in doing so, you can select one which can handle the output current you want. Just have a look at the example charts and see currents going to 15 A.

Comment: 50mA INTVCC is the internal regulator (INTernal VCC) that powers the chip. It doesn't have internal MOSFETs, which makes it a bit more complicated to use, but more flexible: you can optimize output current, efficienct, size and cost depending on what MOSFETs you use it with.

Comment: can you please provide some complete circuit diagram

Comment: It's in the datasheet, but if you don't know how to do this it would save time to buy an off the shelf module (don't ask, I have no idea which one).

Comment: I'm sorry but this is going absolutely nowhere when I try to search ebay and alibaba for buck boosts or 100% duty cycle bucks there not much coming up and even those which do when I ask the sellers they either have no clue or the voltage difference is big so Idk why they advertise them as buckboosts.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mean-well-usa-inc/RSD-60G-12/7706258 , https://www.dfrobot.com/product-504.html

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/semiconductor-circuits-inc/CPE6B18P/11615484

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do this long ago. This was for a 12/24 volt input with no gear change. This will give you a clue in how to proceed. I used a p channel scheme which made drive easy without any fancy highside chips. I could get RDs on of 27 milliohm which was not too expensive and adequate for from memory 6.3 A DC. Using discretes to drive the device was easy because the input gate charge was not too high. Most orthodox hard switch peak current mode chips will not do 100% duty cycle so they would need lots of parts hung around them to do what is wanted. I ended up using no chip.

Comment: Please improve your punctuation! Space goes AFTER the period.

Comment: @winny I think Autistic is not just a name in this case - see the user profile.

Comment: @Arsenal There are software tools available for free to help. One click away.

Comment: oh please just suggest something off the shelf ... or something DIY with circuit diagram and bill of materials thanks.

Comment: @ thermal take .My circuit diagrams are different for different jobs  .Next time you are in NewZealand you could visit .